# Bootstrap NavBar Dropdown Parent Tab Displays "Expand Child Menu" when clicked

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-lists, navbar

I'm using the Bootstrap framework for the first time and so far I'm loving it but I recently came across an issue w/ the navbar component. The issue occurred when I started converting my HTML site to a Wordpress theme. The one instance I have for a dropdown menu tab now displays the term "expand child menu" after being clicked and revealing the submenu. I couldn't find anything related to this issue searching the Github Bootstrap forum either.

Here are two examples below, one w/ the issue and my previous HTML site where it works fine. Click on the "Groups" tab to see what I'm talking about. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help resolve my issue!

http://www.bethpagecamp.com/home/ - (Wordpress testing site w/ the issue for the dropdown tab label)

http://consociatemedia.com/dev/bethpage/ - (initial HTML site w/ no issues for the dropdown label)

Answer (score 2):

i've resolved this issue by adding

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'no_more_jquery');
function no_more_jquery(){
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
}
```

to my functions.php

seems the error was caused due to duplicated jquery scripts.

Cheers

ck

Answer (score 1):

Thanks CK for the response!

It's probably not the most efficient option but I also figured out a solution by disabling some code that was calling that "expand child menu" in the Wordpress theme folder (my-theme/js/function.js).

```
$( '.dropdown-toggle' ).click( function( e ) {
    var _this = $( this );
    e.preventDefault();
    _this.toggleClass( 'toggle-on' );
    _this.next( '.children, .sub-menu' ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
    _this.attr( 'aria-expanded', _this.attr( 'aria-expanded' ) === 'false' ? 'true' : 'false' );
    _this.html( _this.html() === screenReaderText.expand ? screenReaderText.collapse : screenReaderText.expand );
} );
```

I will definitely note your solution for future cases like this. Thanks again!